# Does eclipse has the auto-get & auto-return-value-filled features?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

As the following picture depicted, it costs much time to do get/set & assign operations.

Does eclipse has the auto-get & auto-return-value-filled features, or is there any plugins that support this feature? Maybe a little similar with 'codehelper' in IDEA.

[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv73F.png)

Comment: For what language? There's often an action to create the setters/getters on the Source menu.

Comment: For java. I know how to create the setters/getters on the Source menu, i want  to do auto-insert of all the get method or set method code snipet, 
 just as the picture described.